# How to access specific rows in a pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with what I think is a pandas multi-index data frame. Is there any way to make sure? My data looks like this.

```
            cinc           Outcome   
Side           1         2       1  2
WarNum                               
1       0.146344  0.029989       1  2
4       0.152565  0.056853       1  2
7       0.082757  0.017940       1  2
10      0.076032  0.022553       1  2
13      0.048538  0.005754       1  2
```

When I type in war_cinc.columns. I get the following output.

```
MultiIndex([(   'cinc', 1),
            (   'cinc', 2),
            ('Outcome', 1),
            ('Outcome', 2)],
           names=[None, 'Side'])
```

If I wanted to subset this data, how would I do so? (say I want to get the entire 2nd column of the cinc column of the dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if your df has [`Multiindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), you can do this:

```
isinstance(war_cinc.index, pd.MultiIndex)
```

This will return `True`.

To check for `hierarchical` columns, you can check [`nlevels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.nlevels.html):

```
if len(war_cinc.columns.nlevels) > 1:
```

This will be `True` in your case.

You can get the entire 2nd column like:

```
war_cinc[(   'cinc', 2)]
```

You need to pass all `levels` of the column in a `tuple` to fetch the column values.